# Editing a gridview using the updating event in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What im trying to accomplish is to try to edit a gridview by using the updating event but not sure how to do this. The way im populating the datagrid is putting it into a dataSet and using that as the dataSource and doing a databind. Here is my datagrid below. Any help would be very helpful.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AIRCRAFT" HeaderText="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ENGINE" HeaderText="Product" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LEMAC" HeaderText="Price" />

            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
        </Columns>
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99CCFF" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on the "Update" button, the page does a Postback and then changes the controls of the row in question, allowing the Update.

Besides, it enables 2 buttons: Update and Cancel.

Cancel, will leave the GridView as it was before the first click.
Update, will send the user modified' data to saving.

In order to allow update, you have to capture the RowUpdating event. Something like this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
' Do your Update here
End Sub
```